# Call to undefined method en php con chained methods

Tags: php, objeto, class

tengo este código que al momento de ejecutar me arroja este error "Call to undefined method EZEsports_Customizer_Builder::setName()"

podrían ayudarme con la manera correcta de realizar chained functions con este tipo de builders? Gracias.

```
class EZEsports_Customizer {

        function __construct() {
            $this->section = [];
        }

    }

    class EZEsports_Customizer_Builder {

        function __construct() {
            $this->customizer = new EZEsports_Customizer();
        }

        public function setSection() {
            $this->customizer->section = new EZEsports_Customizer_Section();
            return $this;
        }

        public function setSetting() {
            
        }

        public function setControl() {
            
        }

    }

    class EZEsports_Customizer_Section extends EZEsports_Customizer_Builder {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->customizer->section->name = $name; 
            return $this;
        }

    }

$customizer = new EZEsports_Customizer_Builder();
$customizer->setSection()->setName('Hola');

print_r($customizer);
```

EStoy intentando aplicar Builders para ciertas funciones y me gustaría encadenarlas en un solo llamado, no tengo idea de cual es la manera correcta en PHP.

Comment: Deberías instanciar `EZEsports_Customizer_Section`, que es la que extiende del _Builder_ y tiene el método `setName()`. Instanciando la clase correcta `$customizer = new EZEsports_Customizer_Section();` ya funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema.

Debía retornar la clase en

```
public function setSection() {
    return new EZEsports_Customizer_Section();
}
```

y además crear una variable para el customizerBuilder

```
$customizerBuilder = new EZEsports_Customizer_Builder();
    
    $customizer = $customizerBuilder->setSection()
        ->setName('Hola')
        ->build();

    print_r($customizer);
```